# What does it mean for an object to be a colimit of another object in a category?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I understand what colimits are, and what it means for an object to be a colimit, however I have come across the expression "$x$ is a colimit of $y$", where $x$ and $y$ are both particular objects in a given category. Does anyone have any thoughts on what this could mean?

Comment: Where have you come across this?

Comment: University work, not a published text.

Comment: It's not good writing. It could be a mistake, or could mean that there's a diagram, all of whose object values are $y$, whose colimit is $x$. For instance, every abelian group is a colimit of a diagram, all of whose objects are $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your interpretation is what I took it to mean, although yeah it's not very clear. Thanks

Comment: @Kevin: that is a tempting conjecture but it's not true! See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204792/is-every-abelian-group-a-colimit-of-copies-of-z

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! I was about to say $\mathbb{Z}^2$ but then got tricked thinking about presentations.

Comment: @Daven: Can you add more context? Doesn't $y$ happen to be an object in the category of some $I$-shaped *diagrams* of a category $A$ (that is, in $Fun(I,A)=A^I$)?